# Xcode force_load not working for simulator build

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

I am using Xcode 4 and LLVM 2 for a workspace which has two projects (A and B) in it. The main project (A) links against the binary of the other project (B) which builds a static library.

Project B contains categories so in order for it to link into A properly I set the ObjC and all_load linker flags. This however caused problems because some of our libraries that I use have symbols that should not be loaded so I tried to move over to using force_load specifically on the library file of project B.

-force_load $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libB.a

This makes things work on the device however in the simulator the app crashes because categories from project B are not being linked in.

Any idea why force_load works differently on device and simulator?

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 5):

Try `-Wl,-force_load,$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libB.a`; IIRC, it's a known issue that Apple LLVM Compiler 2.0 doesn't honor `-force-load`.